# MySQL: how many rows of a certain kind were inserted in the last second

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two mysql tables, `a` and `b`, in a one-to-many relationship (`b` is actually a linker table of a many-to-many relationship between `a` and some other table):

```
mysql> DESCRIBE a;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id    | bigint(30)   | NO   | PRI | 0                 |                             |
| date  | timestamp    | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE b;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a_id  | bigint(30)  | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| field | smallint(6) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As new rows are inserted frequently, I need to know how many rows were inserted in table `b` in the last second.
I also need to distinguish between rows with `b.field` greater than, equal to, or less than `0` (`{somedate}` is the time one second ago):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE a.date >= '{somedate}' AND b.field > 0

SELECT count(*) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE a.date >= '{somedate}' AND b.field = 0

SELECT count(*) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE a.date >= '{somedate}' AND b.field < 0
```

These three queries were taking around 5 seconds, so I tried to optimize them by putting them all in the same query:

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN b.field > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    sum(CASE WHEN b.field = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    sum(CASE WHEN b.field < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE a.date >= '{somedate}'
```

However, I'm not sure if this improved anything at all.

My performance concern is simply because I'm interested in what happened in the last second, so obviously this isn't very useful if the query takes more than one second.

How can I improve these queries' performance? Preferably without having to modify the tables.

More info:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE a\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: a
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date_index` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE b\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: b
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `a_id` bigint(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `field` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`,`field`),
  KEY `a_id_fk` (`a_id`),
  KEY `field_fk` (`field`),
  CONSTRAINT `a_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `a` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `field_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`field`) REFERENCES `c` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)   

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id WHERE a.date >= '2014-10-15' AND b.field = 0;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys            | key      | key_len | ref             | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref    | PRIMARY,field_fk,a_id_fk | field_fk | 2       | const           | 40698 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY  | 8       | database.b.a_id |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id WHERE a.date >= '2014-10-15' AND b.field > 0;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys            | key      | key_len | ref             | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | range  | PRIMARY,field_fk,a_id_fk | field_fk | 2       | NULL            | 370846 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY  | 8       | database.b.a_id |      1 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------+--------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT sum(CASE WHEN b.field > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN b.field = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), sum(CASE WHEN b.field < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id WHERE a.date >= '2014-10-15';
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------+-----------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys   | key      | key_len | ref             | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------+-----------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | index  | PRIMARY,a_id_fk | field_fk | 2       | NULL            | 741976 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY  | 8       | database.b.a_id |      1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------+-----------------+--------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please view the following link you may get and idea.
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65484/how-to-monitor-the-number-of-rows-inserted-per-second-and-per-minute-into-mysql

Comment: Interesting. But how could I distinguish between rows with b.field greater than, equal to, or less than zero?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: It's in my question. That's why I use three queries. Please let me know if you need further clarification.